# Kubernetes redirect subdomain requests for each pod

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

Is there a routing option that could route incoming requests to pod DNS name?.

I am aware of subdomain routing but I only saw hardcoded paths examples for the `- host` parameter.

Each pod will be created for a new account (with the same software) and routing to this pod will need to be supported automatically for new incoming requests.

As you can see in the picture there are **two different requests** (can be more) to the same pod `http://nnnnnna.cybearjinni.com`, **this is the case for each request in the picture** and the number of pods gets bigger for each user.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify the problem to make it [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How exactly did you set up your cluster? Which versions did you use? Please add your yaml files.

Comment: I'm not sure you'd be able to achieve this without creating a specific tuple of Deployment, Service and Ingress for each subdomain. The naming of each subdomain would be independent of the pod names. Like, `nnnnna` would be part of your actual Deployment name.